# React "value" prop not reaching DOM if set to 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that renders a `<progress/>` element styled by Bootstrap. The `<progress/>` element takes two props, `value` and `max`, and uses these to draw a progress bar. It works great most of the time. However, when `value=0`, the `value` prop itself doesn't appear in the DOM. This causes the component to show up as a progress bar that's "pulsing" (ie., the bar part of it scrolls from left to right forever).

That is, the following code is returned by the React `render` method:

`<progress value=0 max=255>0/255</progress>`

But this is what reaches the actual DOM:

`<progress max=255>0/255</progress>`

What causes this? It works in all other cases (that is, 0 < value < max) just fine. How can I make it render properly when `value=0`?

Edit: the `render()` function is below:

```
var barColor = "info";

if (row.fraction <= 0.25)
    barColor = "danger";

else if (row.fraction <= 0.50)
    barColor = "warning";

return (
    <div>
        <Col md={10}>
            <progress className={"progress progress-" + barColor} value={row.quantity} max={row.total}>
                {row.quantity + "/" + row.total}
            </progress>
        </Col>
        <Col md={2}>
            <span style={{fontSize: "12px"}}>{row.quantity + "/" + row.total}</span>
        </Col>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Can you post your render method?

Comment: @mrlew I added it in an edit.

Comment: The only thing that comes in mind without looking at the full source is that someway `row.quantity`is `undefined` or `null`, causing the value prop not being rendered. Can you `console.log` it to check if the value is really zero?

Comment: @mrlew I thought that also, but `console.log` shows quantity as 0. Even if I put `value={0}` in there, the same thing happens. It seems to be some sort of optimization by React or Javascript.

Comment: Maybe converting value to string? `{value.toString()}`

Comment: @mrlew Good idea! Unfortunately it didn't do the trick :( This is a pretty strange issue. For now I've just made the "0" value a special case because I hate that pulsing progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a (hacky?) solution.

Somehow the value 0 is not being passed to this specific html component by `React.createElement`. The [`progressbar` specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) says the value must be a float. So, converting to a two decimal number made the value `0.00` to be properly passed.

Try changing your code to: `<progress value={parseFloat(row.quantity).toFixed(2)} />`

It should do the trick.

Comment: Awesome, that did it! I had tried `0.0` but I guess I needed that extra bit of precision. Thanks!

Comment: Also I wrote this, I found that this behavior is a [know react bug](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6704). And apparently is already fixed.

Comment: Wow just 13 days ago. Thanks for the heads up!